# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. while converting np array to float32

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I took a bunch of images converted them into gray then stored them into img_data_list then i converted them to a numpy array everything works fine untill now here's part of code that works

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

people = ['s1', 's2']
num_classes = 2
img_data_list = []
labels = []
valid_images = [".jpg",".gif",".png"]

for index, person in enumerate(people):
  print(index)
  dir_path = 'I:\\project_face_detection\\face_detetion\\training_data\\' + person
  for img_path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(img_path)
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue

    img_data = cv2.imread(dir_path + '\\' + img_path)
    # convert image to gray
    img_data=cv2.cvtColor(img_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_data_list.append(img_data)
    labels.append(index)


img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
```

but when I try to convert the array into float32 data type I get the ValueError

```
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
```

here's the error

```
 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

here's how my images are stored

```
- training_data
   - s1
       - 0.jpg
       - 1.jpg
   - s2
      - 0.jpg
      - ......
```

If you guys can help me out in any way I'd be grateful thanks for looking into it :) .

Comment: Instead of applying astype('float32') later on the combined list, try applying the same when adding the image to the list

Comment: Tell us about `img_data`, `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: Probably, you have images with different sizes. If so, you cannot do it this way.

Comment: @AnkurGoel  do you mean "img_data = np.array(img_data_list,dtype='float32')" i tried that it didn't work same error

Comment: @hpaulj img_data is initially where I stored my images which I later converted into a numpy array when i do img_data.shape i get (876,)  I am converting dtype to float32 so i can divide by 255.0 the whole array in the later step

Comment: @abhinayoja no i meant, img_data_list.append(np.array(img_data,dtype='float32'))

Comment: @AnkurGoel just tried it I am getting the following error   error: (-4) Failed to allocate 47775744 bytes in function cv::OutOfMemoryErro

Comment: And the `dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj initially the array is in the form of object i am converting dtype to float so that i can divide with 255

Comment: It's object dtype because it contains arrays that differ in shape.  The astype conversion doesn't work on that.

Comment: @hpaulj i have images taken with different cameras with different resolution could that be the reason for this error